# IOS Swift defining own app-settings in own class

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

im new in Swift and X-Code. Im searching for a way import a own defined class (best case in an own document). I want store all needed settings (text-snippets and app-settings) in this file. For example:

```
class snippetsAndSettings {
    // e.g translations
    let t_welcome: String   = "Welcome to my App"
    let t_share: String     = "Social Share Buttons"
    let t_rate: String      = "Rate"

    // e.g settings 
    let s_weburl: String    = "http://www.mypage.com/webservice.php"
    let s_slider: Bool      = false
    let s_bgColor: String   = "#ff9900"
    let s_tColor: String    = "#222222"
    let t_shadow: String? // Bool or colorString!
}
```

I want to use this class on every app-page. But i can not import the for for example in ViewController.swift

My questions:

1. In which format do i have to save the file (snippetsAndSettings)? Cocoa Class
2. How can i import the file in my ViewController.Swift
3. Is this a common way to store own app-settings in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to store settings is via [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html). You can setup your default values in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. For example:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([
    "volume": 100,
    "showShadows": true
    ])
```

To get these back, you would do:

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("volume")`

and

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("showShadows")`

In Swift 5, it now looks like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
  "volume": 100,
  "showShadows": true
])
```

And to get it back

```
let volume = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "volume")
let showShadows = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showShadows")
```

For translations, you should look in to [Internationalization and Localization](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

Comment: Its not a translation, The app will have just one language. I just don't like "Strings" in my Code.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend having a static object with strings in it, but would rather go for localisation with only a single language and still using the `NSLocalizedString` method. However, I'll leave that up to you

Comment: To understand how to import static classes. i want to know how i can import them. I created a Swift-file "snippetsAndSettings" in my projectfolder and added the Class  snippetsAndSettings into it. When i type in my Viewcontroller.swift  under "import Foundation =>import snippetsAndSettings", i get the error "No such module..."

Comment: Each target within your application is its own swift module. This means that you'll be able to "see" your `snippetsAndSettings` class from any other files within the same target. See [Modules and Source Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID4)

Comment: Thank you for help. i just instantiated "snippetsAndSettings". and it works fine.